# (go-twitter) cannot use extended tweet mode while streaming

Tags: go, twitter

Sorry I am using Go Twitter, and my problem is that I cannot find any way to get extended mode for tweets while streaming. There seems to be no way for me to activate this in the StreamFilterParams.

Is it the case that it is not possible ?

for example, there is no way to set extended mode in params here : https://github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/blob/master/twitter/streams.go

am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

The streaming API already returns extended Tweets, so it is not possible to set that parameter. There’s an additional set of values inside the Tweet object with the full text of the Tweet, in streaming only.